# Access DOM using browser object in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox extension in javascript, from that script I need to access the DOM object using browser window object. How do I achieve this?

When I tried `window.document.deafultView.innerHeight` in my extension, I was getting an exception.

I don't know how to get access to the DOM object using window object from my plugin.

Comment: what kind of extension/plugin are you writing? is it a browser extension? for what browser?

Comment: @PascalBeyeler There are 2 tags on the question - `firefox` and `firefox addon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://semanticvoid.com/blog/2006/06/01/accessing-the-dom-from-within-the-firefox-extension/ you can access the DOM with:

```
// Get the content of the currently displaying window
var win = window.content;

// Access the document within the window as follows
win.document.getElementById(‘xyz’);
```